# Column headers are not aligned in dataframe - Python

Tags: python, dataframe, data-structures, header

I have the following output of a dataframe `>>> print(total_year)`:

```
          value  year
Area
27.4.a  46728.0  2006
```

The structure of the dataframe is not in the way that I want since the headers of the columns (`Area` , `value` and `year`) are not aligned well. The preferred outcome:

```
           
Area      value  year
27.4.a  46728.0  2006
```

What is a convenient way to obtain the preferred outcome?

Comment: `.reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your issue, while keeping the index values:

```
df = df.rename_axis(None)
```